# How to display button opposite of level in React?

Tags: reactjs

How to display button opposite of its status. Suppose its showing open then the button should appear Withdraw and if the status is appearing Withdraw button should appear Open in Reactjs.

I have a Json object which carries the necessary information.

Here is code is what I have had tried..

```
const initial = {
  description: [
    {
      name: 'Alex',
      level: 'open',
    },
    {
      name: 'Sycus',
      level: 'open',
    },
    {
      name: 'Rasku',
      level: 'Withdraw',
    }
  ]
}

export default function App() {

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initial)
  const [show , setshow] = React.useState(true)

  const handleClick = () => {
    return 
  }

  const butFunction = () => {
      return state.description.map(sub => { 
          const { level } = sub
          return (
            if(level === 'open'){
              <button>Withdraw</button>
            }
            else{
              <button>Open</buton>
            }
          )
      })
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {
              state.description.map(desc => (
                <tr>
                  <td>
                  {desc.name}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                  {desc.level}
                  </td>
                <td>

                { show && butFunction()}
                </td>
                </tr>
              ))
              }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `map` inside the `butFunction`. That would print 3 buttons for every entry. Instead, pass the function a parameter telling it which level it is.

Example below:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initial)
  const [show , setshow] = React.useState(true)

  // Use the level passed in
  const butFunction = (level) => {
    if(level === 'open'){
      return <button>Withdraw</button>;
    } else {
      return <button>Open</button>;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            {state.description.map(desc => (
              <tr>
                <td>
                  {desc.name}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {desc.level}
                </td>
                <td>
                  {show && butFunction(desc.level)} // <- Pass it here
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Not it will only return one button per entry.

Comment: Oh you can't use an `if` inside a return block like that. You didn't include the error in the question so I didn't even catch that part. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rendering two different buttons for two conditions you can use ternary operator to conditionally change the text of single button like this:

```
return(
    <button>{level===‘open’?’withdraw’:’open’}</button>
)
```